# Replace map to vector

Tags: c++, vector, stdmap

I replaced map into vector< pair < long, Object > > because of memory. I need rest some memory (even a few Mb) and I read that maps need more virtual memory. So I've met one problem:

```
bool CClass::generateMap(int num,  const long*& fg,
                                      CObjekt *pObjekt) const
{
    foId_t tmpFo = fg[OBJECT_IDX];
    CAttribute *pAttribute;
    objectMap_it tmp_it = pObjekt->objectMap.find(tmpFo);
    if(tmp_it != (pObject->objectMap.end()))
    {
        pAttribute = (*tmp_it).second;
    }
    else
    {
        pAttribute = new COlageAttribute();
        pObject->objectMap[tmpFo] = pAttribute; 
    }
    if((generateAttributeMap(fg, pAttribute) == false))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So. And now I want to replace objectMap map to Vector of pairs. But I have problem: I wanted use for loop but first time my Vector return size 0, and that is not work correctly. I think I did unwise mistake, so I put my example code here:

```
for(int i=0; i<pObject->objectVector.size(); i++)
{
    test = pObject->objectVector[i].first;
    if(test==tmpFo)
    {
        pAttribute = pObject->objectVector[i].second;
    }


    else
    {

        pAttribute = new CAttribute();
        pObject->objectVector[it].second = pAttribute;
    }
```

}

Comment: Is that an else clause for a for loop...? Also if you're actually dealing with so much data memory is becoming an issue, do remember that maps are *vastly* faster at looking up data than a plain list. You might run into a time problem instead.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen It depends.  If he keeps the data sorted, and uses `std::lower_bound` for look-ups, an `std::vector` could be significantly faster than an `std::map`.  (On the other hand, an insertion or an erase could invalidate any iterators into it.)

Comment: `map<int, int> mymap = { { 0, 1}, {2, 3} }; vector<pair<int, int>> myvec(mymap.begin(), mymap.end());`

Comment: To me it looks like the kind of question where you use `X` to solve `Y` but the `X` you chose is not appropriate.

Comment: if belog to for loop. Rerito, I mean that I need to replace searching by iterators with searching by elements, because I have no iterators at current element( like find in map). So I tried change the code with for loop but I know it will not work because at the beginning I have no size for vector, and I am not sure how many dates I will have. So I put exemple code for retrieve some ideas. If do you need details feel free to ask. @Matti Virkkunen, I suppose that map will work faster, but now I have problem with capacity, so it's my only chance to resolve my problem.

Comment: Take a look at [`boost::flat_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx), it offers a similar interface to `std::map` but implemented more like a `std::vector`. That will mean you don't need to rewrite all the code using `map::find` etc.

Comment: @JonathanWakely thx for idea. I will read about flat_map

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, as James said, lookup in a sorted vector is much faster than lookup in a map (because there's no pointer chasing) and even a linear search of an unsorted vector can be faster than a map when the number of elements is small

Comment: @JonathanWakely: His map seemed to be essentially a map from a pointer to a pointer and he said he was running into a memory usage problem with it, so it's most definitely not small. (...or he just has a lot of them, I guess)

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, good point, he's not likely to be running out of memory with 10 elements :)

Comment: Ok I resolved my problem with repleacing maps to vectors of pairs, but I have no more memory on my mobile phone (win ce 5.0) Any ideas, which container could to help me?